# Store checkbox values in firebase using android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on recommendation application I using firebase to store information about user.I have used checkboxes for health status information.
I want to save all the checkbox values I selected.but in my code if I check more then one checkbox it always save the last checkbox.

This is my code How can I fix it to store all checked values?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

   Toolbar toolbar =findViewById(R.id.toolbarotherpages);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


databaseUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://bonappetit-808c5.firebaseio.com").getReference("users");
users = new ArrayList<>();

addusername= findViewById(R.id.editTextname);
addphone=findViewById(R.id.editTextphone2);
mFirstCheckBox=findViewById(R.id.cbox1);
mSecondCheckBox=findViewById(R.id.cbox2);
mThirdCheckBox=findViewById(R.id.cbox3);
addhealthstatus=findViewById(R.id.editTexthealthstatus);


btnsignup =findViewById(R.id.buttonsignup2);

btnsignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Signup dosignup = new Signup(); // this is the Asynctask
        dosignup.execute("");

       }
   });
 }

protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
//attaching value event listener
databaseUser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        //clearing the previous artist list
        users.clear();

        //iterating through all the nodes
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            //getting artist
            users user = postSnapshot.getValue(users.class);
            //adding artist to the list
            users.add(user);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
}

   public class Signup extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
  String z = "";
  Boolean isSuccess = false;
   String username = addusername.getText().toString();
    String phone = addphone.getText().toString();
    String healthstatus = addhealthstatus.getText().toString();

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    if (username.trim().equals("") || phone.trim().equals("")) {
        z += "Please fill in all fields";
     } else {
        int count = 0;
        for (users user2 : users) {
            if (user2.getPhonenumber().equals(phone)) {
                count = 1;
            }
        }
        if (count == 0) {
            try {

                if(mFirstCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                    users user = new users(username, phone,"Diabetes");
                    databaseUser.child(phone).setValue(user);
                    addusername.setText("");
                    addphone.setText("");
                    addhealthstatus.setText("");
                }

                if(mSecondCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                    users user = new users(username, phone, "pressure");
                    databaseUser.child(phone).setValue(user);
                    addusername.setText("");
                    addphone.setText("");
                    addhealthstatus.setText("");
                }

                if(mThirdCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                    users user = new users(username, phone, 
                        healthstatus);
                    databaseUser.child(phone).setValue(user);
                    addusername.setText("");
                    addphone.setText("");
                    addhealthstatus.setText("");
                }

                z = "Account created";
                isSuccess = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                z = "Mobile number was used";
                isSuccess = false;
            }
        }
        }
        return z;
      }
     }
```

Comment: What is the problem you're facing with this code? Also if it is something related to your database then do attach your database structure too.

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected checked values you can use **Switch case** following code

`public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {`

```
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

    switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.checkBox1:
         ....


    break;
    case R.id.checkBox2:
        ......

    break;

    case R.id.checkBox3:
        ......

        break;`
```